# Is "blow wise to" a dialectal/archaic phrase? What is its etymology?

Tags: etymology, phrases, slang, phrase-meaning

> But **blow wise to** this, buddy, blow wise to this: Never play cards with a man called Doc. Never eat at a place called Mom’s. Never sleep with a woman whose troubles are worse than your own. Never let nobody talk you into shaking another man’s jolt. And never you cop another man’s plea. I’ve tried ‘em all and I know. They don’t work. (Nelson Algren, *A Walk on the Wild Side*)

It seems all search results of "blow wise to", very few in number, all point back to this book. [Wiktionary's entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow_wise_to) also cites this same sentence. It doesn't seem to appear anywhere else. Although Algren famously uses a lot of slang in his works, I can't find any origin/contemporary currency for this one. Are there other instantiations/attestations of this usage? What's its etymology? And what exactly is the phrase? Is "blow to something/someone" the basic phrase?

Comment: The basic phrase is definitely _wise (to something)_. I’ve never seen or heard it used with the verb _blow_ before, but it’s common enough with verbs like _grow_ or _become_.

Comment: **Blow wise** is probably a locally understood idiom for [**wise up**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wise-up). You forgot to mention *"shaking another man’s jolt"*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Haha, good call! Having read some Algren, I actually know what "shake someone's jolt" means. Prison slang, apparently.

Comment: Hmmm so the apparent wisdom in the quote did not spare any jail / gaol time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For its definition, origin and exact phrase: *[A Dictionary of the Underworld: British and American](https://books.google.com/books?id=LEXeCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT178&dq=blow%20wise&pg=PT178#v=onepage&q=blow%20wise&f=false)*:

> »**blow wise (to)**. To grasp the meaning (of), to inform oneself (about),
>   to become informed: Dec. 1930, The American Mercury, James P. Burke
>   ('The Argot of the Racketeers'), 'Blow wise to what I'm spieling',
>   1934, Howard N. Rose

And in *[Cassell's Dictionary of Slang](https://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&lpg=PA137&dq=%22blow%20wise%22&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q=%22blow%20wise%22&f=false)*

> **blow wise** v. [late 19C+l (US) To see where one's interests lie, to
>   understand; blow v. and wise n.

From my perusal of the [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blow#etymonline_v_13630) of blow, I could find no definite connection.  "To bloom, blossom, put forth [flowers]" could possibly be related.

Finally,

> Is "blow to something/someone" the basic phrase?

I do not believe so. And for current usage in Ame ... nothing much: